# How to skip rows based on regex with pandas.read_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read in an excel sheet with pandas.read_excel. Its skiprows argument allows for skipping rows by supplying the row numbers. However, how can we skip rows based on a pattern match? I have different excel sheets where the number of rows I need to skip is variable so supplying the number of rows isn't going to work for my use case. Is there a way I can supply a pattern - for e.g. skip all rows before a row that contains a specific string (say 'Test')? If this can't be accomplished with pandas read_excel, is there an alternative workaround to read the excel into dataframe this way? Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you could create a list which references the index of the pattern and then loop over this using each of these indexes as the argument for `skip_rows` but without sample data and the pattern we can't provide a more "concrete" answer

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to read the entire excel sheet into a dataframe and afterwards drop the unwanted rows. As a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read out first sheet of excel workbook
df = pd.read_excel('workbook.xlsx')

# Find label of the first row where the value 'Test' is found (within column 0)
row_label = (df.iloc[:, 0] == 'Test').idxmax()

# Drop all rows above the row with 'Test'
df = df.loc[row_label:, :]
```