# Automatically skip initial rows to pandas.read_excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have XLS/XLSX spreadsheets exported by different sources that have to be treated in the same way by a developed Python software.

Some time the spreadsheet have a default layout (unique sheet and first rows as header) and can be directly read by `pd.read_excel(file_name)`. Other times the spreadsheet have 2 pages ("meta information" and "data"), the first can be easily ignored but the second have a particular layout:

```
project name
...
author name
%empty line%
header1 -- header2 -- header3 -- header4 ...
   x    --    x    --   x    --   x
   x    --    x    --   x    --   x
...
   x    --    x    --   x    --   x
totalization
```

The problem is the presence of initial lines with "no-data information" and last rows with some total that I don't have the previous information of how many are.

Despite be easy to ignore the last rows after the read procedure, the first rows generate errors on the software.

I could ignore those initial rows through the `pd.read_excel(foo, skiprows=)` directive but initially I don't know the number of rows to be ignored. I just know that such rows have maximum 1 to 2 columns and a possible empty row after.

Question:
Is it possible `pd.read_excel` begin to read the block with the rows that have maximum number of columns?
If not, is it possible to load the spreadsheet into the memory check the first rows and pass to `pandas` just the rows of my interest?

This question may be related with:
[How to skip rows based on regex with pandas.read_excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332613/how-to-skip-rows-based-on-regex-with-pandas-read-excel)

Comment: If there's a clear sentinel for where your data begin (i.e. always after the first empty line, first column header is always "XXX") then you might write a wrapper that reads in the file twice. The first time quickly read in a small number of rows that you know is longer than your header, say `nrows=25`, and determine the row where your data begin using that sentinel. Then read the entire file specifying that derived value for skiprows.

Comment: Yes, I can accomplish this by `pandas.read_excel(foo, nrows=25)`, do some check and after do `pd.read_excel(foo, skiprows=)`. But there is not a better approach that do not imply in a double read procedure? I did some tests and it become time expensive too the software (basically using the double of time read of the full read procedure).

Comment: Ah your files are small then I assume. Otherwise just reading 25 lines should be very fast, compared to say reading 1M lines. (But perhaps .xlsx is different). Sadly I often find these problems really difficult to solve at this point. The best solution is to somehow go back to whatever is producing the data and ensure the ignorable lines are all proceeded with some special character (like '%') that you can specify with the `comment` argument. But often that's not the case.

Comment: No, the file are "huge" to spreadsheets about 80MB. The aggravating it that I had to use `pandas.read_excel(foo, engine='xlrd')` due (I think) the older libraries used on the server/exportation side. The time used to read the complete file or just few lines become de same. I am exploring something as `io = pandas.ExcelFile(file_name)` to get information before the full read.